# Java Android: Make a word (from a paragraph) into a button

Tags: java, android, button, text, hyperlink

I searched for some answers, but came up empty, maybe I'm not wording my question correctly.

Basically I want a hyper link, except it has a java on click listener attached to it, instead of an html link.  I have some paragraphs of text and certain words are highlighted, I want the user to be able to click those words and it executes a function.

Any thoughts or website tutorials?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Linkify class to achieve what you want. [Here is a full tutorial that will help you](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html)

Comment: I'm not sure that will work, or maybe I don't fully understand it.  How can you make it call a function after clicking it?
But your answer did put me on the right track to finding ClickableSpans, which is what I think I'm looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: when you click the linkified text it will fire an intent which could be handled by an activity (which in your case could be the same activity that has the text view with some help of the onNewIntent function).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I'm still new to all of this stuff.  Thanks for the explanation.